# third party Oauth authentication and email verification

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, backend

I'm working on a personal project spring boot for the back-end and android kotlin
now I want to add third-party authentication like Facebook and google like any other well-respected app
after surfing the web and asking chat-GPT I have arrived at noting
what I'm trying to do is

- in my Android app, the user will sign up via either Google or Facebook
- the selected Oauth provider will return an object that contains some token
- I will send the token to my back-end and there I can send this token for verification to the
  chosen Oauth provider
- if that token is legit then I will generate a JWT  for that user and use it instead
  throughout the application

what I need is a way for my spring-boot back-end to verify some kind of token that I can get from the sign-in button via either Google or Facebook in the android

Comment: Have you looked into OIDC flows? Here's a Baeldung example for OIDC [Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect). There are multiple ways to verify the Id Token, some identity provider have a verfication endpoint e.g.

Comment: i will check it out